# Image selected for native_splash_screen package only shows on virtual device

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, splash-screen, android-virtual-device

I declared an image and a background image in my pubspec.yaml file which both work perfectly fine on my AVD but unluckily the image (that should be shown in the center) is not being displayed when starting the application on a physical android device. The background image is being displayed but instead of the image I have selected to be in the center of the splash screen, there is the Flutter logo being shown. The size of the background image is 154KB and the size of the centered image is 54.9KB. I haven't tried it on any apple devices yet.

````
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.0

flutter_native_splash:

  android: true
  ios: true
  web: true

  image: "images/splash_screen.png"
  background_image: "images/splash_screen_background.png"```
````

Comment: The first thing you should try is updating to the latest version.  `flutter_native_splash` is currently at version `2.2.19`.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is running on  Android 12 or above you have to add the following

```
android_12:
   image: "images/splash_screen.png"
   color: "#42a5f5" //your background color
```

NOTE: You cannot use background image for Android 12 or above. Follow [this](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen) guide for android devices

Comment: But the background image is working, its just the centered image that wont be shown. Instead there is just the flutter logo and i dont know why